# Amazon AWS EC2 disable access to installed application using public IP4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elb

1. I created a new instance of amazon aws EC2.
2. I installed an apache2 web server, with wordpress app.
3. I configured my domain name, and added a load balancer to redirect to https using an amazon public ssl certificate.
4. All work perfectly and I can access to my web site using https://mysiteweb.com/
5. Even when I access to my app site `http://mysiteweb.com`, the redirection is performed to `https://`.

The prorblem is I can still access to my app using the EC2 public IP4: http://XX.XXX.XXX.XX and here no redirection id performed.

Same think with the DNS public (IP4): `ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com`, no redirection here also.

How can resolve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the security group of your instance to **only allow inbound access on port 80/443** from the security group attached to the load balancer.

Your load balancer has at least one security group attached such as that below

```
sg-123456
INBOUND RULES
| Protocol | Port  | Source    |
--------------------------------
| TCP      | 80    | 0.0.0.0/0 | 
| TCP      | 443   | 0.0.0.0/0 |
```

You would then update the instance security group to match the below example here `sg-123456` is the load balancers security group.

```
sg-123457
INBOUND RULES
| Protocol | Port  | Source    |
--------------------------------
| TCP      | 80    | sg-123456 | 
| TCP      | 443   | sg-123456 |
```

By doing this you prevent anything other than the load balancer performing any HTTP requests on your instance.

You can further increase security of your instance and prevent this scenario  by moving your instance into a private subnet so that no one is able to connect to it publicly.

**In addition** configure the web server you're running to redirect any host name that is not the target hostnames to be the hostname you're expecting.

This can be accomplished by adding a default VHOST that catches any requests, this will be the first that you have added in web servers such as Apache and Nginx. Then add an additional vhost with the `ServerAlias` set to the domain you're anticipating the user landing on.

By doing this it prevents crawls on your load balancer returning your site.

Comment: _"You should update the security group of your instance to only allow inbound access on port 80/443 from the security group attached to the load balancer."_


You mean in my inbound security group and under the two lines for 80 and 443: instead of putting 0.0.0.0/0 I put the load balancer address??

Comment: You can reference the security group, start typing `sg-` and it will list security groups :)

Comment: Amazon allows logical reference, for certain resources such as security groups and prefix lists in security group rules which really helps :)

Comment: That looks correct as long as thats the instance security group, and the sg- is the security group attached to the load balancer :)

Comment: Sorry I deleted my previous comment: https://imgur.com/P400lMq
(Just for all future reader: this is the picture that Chris says its look correct)

Comment: Chris: I think only the 80 port have to be configured with the security group, not the 443 port.
When I configure both It doesn't work. only when I configure 80 port Its work. And my problem of public IP4 address is resolved

Comment: Yes its whichever ports your instance listens on :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be rectified, by configuring the security group (SG) for your EC2 instance should be configured to allowed **incoming connections from the SG of your load balancer**:

- [Security groups for your Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-update-security-groups.html)
- [Security groups for instances in a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-groups.html#elb-vpc-instance-security-groups)